# Render single document in React with Meteor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

To render a list of documents, I use `.map()` on a function that returns an array from the subscription:

```
{this.getApplications().map( (application) => {
  return application.name;
})}
```

But when I want to render a single document like this:

```
export default class ApplicationForm extends TrackerReact(React.Component) {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        subscription: {
            applications: Meteor.subscribe('applications')
        }
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.state.subscription.applications.stop();
  }

  getSingleApplication() {

    const applicationDoc = Applications.find().fetch();

    if (applicationDoc) {
        return applicationDoc[0];
    }
  }

  render () {

    const name = this.getSingleApplication().name;

    return (
        <div>
            {name}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

I guess I have been missing out on some basic javascript.

Or it might have to do with subscriptions not being ready at page load?

Comment: Can we see more code?

Comment: `this.getSingleApplication()` is returning undefined. Not much else we can do.

Comment: `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` - means you need to learn javascript... getSingleApplication returns undefined...

Comment: @KellyJAndrews `this.getSingleApplication()` returns undefined before the subscription is ready, when it is ready the document is returned.

Comment: Then you need to wait until it's not returning undefined before trying to get anything out of it.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews Yes, any tips on how to do a sexy implementation of Subscription.ready() in this context?

Comment: If undefined, don't, else do. Not really sexy.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews Ye, started doing that, but the document will have a lot of properties, and I'd have to check for each one before rendering. Or do I? #tiredHobbyProgrammer

Comment: no clue - but this seems useful - https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/data-loading-react/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, use `.findOne()` when you want to find a single document. This returns an object instead of a cursor so you don't need to `.fetch()` or `.map()`.

```
getSingleApplication() {
  return Applications.findOne(); 
}
```

Then you need to code defensively in case nothing is found (which can happen if your subscription isn't ready for example).

```
render () {

  const app = this.getSingleApplication();
  const name = app && app.name;

  if (name) { // assuming you don't want to render anything if there is no name
    return (
      <div>
        {app.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! The document will have many properties, will I need an if-statement for each property?

Comment: Depends. Will all the properties always be there together or can they appear in any combination? If they are always there together then just do `if(app)`

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have never used Meteor and this is not tested.

You need to have some way to react to your subscription being 'ready', and if I understand the docs correctly you do this by passing a callback function when you subscribe.

So you need

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        ready: false,
        subscription: {
            applications: Meteor.subscribe('applications', () => this.setState({ready: true})
        }
    }
  }
```

and in render:

```
render () {
    if (!this.state.ready) return null;
    const name = this.getSingleApplication().name;

    return (
        <div>
            {name}
        </div>
    );
  }
```